# What is the difference between user_description and description?

Tags: author

In the codex page for [`the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta), the list of fields available for the function lists both `user_description` and `description`. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_description` field is alias of `description` field. Nothing more. If you echo both of them on one page, you will see that they are identical and shows the same information about user's bio.